# How to avoid overlapping of X-axis values and Y-axis values in Radar chart?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, radar-chart

I am trying to show the Radar chart with 6 X-axis labels. Currently the name of the X-axis labels and its values are getting overlapped. How can we avoid the overlapping of X-axis labels and values?

I am using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) for Radar chart.

Please find the screenshot here:

[image]

Here total invested and Total returns are getting overlapped with their respective values.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Your solution fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max values for your axes is 100, but you have graphed values exceeding that maximum. As a result, value labels are overlapping with axis labels.